# Cloud functions show they are working but I never receive a notification in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to my device when something happens in my Firestore DB.

If I send a notification from within the Cloud Messaging section of Firebase, I receive the notification. However, if I add a document or change something inside an existing document, the functions I have created show that they have been executed but I don't receive any notifications.

How does FCM know which device to send the push notification to? In my code, I don't provide the device token in the Firebase function. Maybe this is my problem but in the video I watched, the guy doesn't provide it either.

Here are my Cloud functions:

```
exports.newTrxnNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("/company/{companyId}/trxns/{trxnsId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const newData = snapshot.data();
      const trxn = context.params.trxnsId;
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: String(newData.title),
          body: String(newData.body),
        },
        topic: trxn,
      };
      return admin.messaging().send(payload);
    });

exports.updateTrxnsNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("/company/{companyId}/trxns/{trxnsId}")
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
      const newData = snapshot.data();
      const trxn = context.params.trxnsId;
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: String(newData.title),
          body: String(newData.body),
        },
        topic: trxn,
      };
      return admin.messaging().send(payload);
    });
```

Here is the code from my firebase_api.dart file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

// Use this YouTube video for guidance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0zGEbiDJcQ

Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Title: ${message.notification?.title}');
  }
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Body: ${message.notification?.body}');
  }
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Payload: ${message.data}');
  }
}

class FirebaseApi {
  final firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final androidChannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High_Importance_Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications',
    importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
  );
  final localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message == null) return;
  }

  Future initLocalNotification() async {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android);

    await localNotifications.initialize(
      settings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
        final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload as String));
        handleMessage(message);
      },
    );

    final platform = localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
    await platform?.createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
  }

  Future initPushNotifications() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (message) {
        final notification = message.notification;
        if (notification == null) return;

        localNotifications.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                androidChannel.id, androidChannel.name,
                channelDescription: androidChannel.description,
                icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher'),
          ),
          payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    //final fcmToken = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    initPushNotifications();
    initLocalNotification();
  }
}
```

Here are the logs for the newTrxnNotification function. They don't tell me anything but maybe someone can see something in them:

```
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution took 862 ms, finished with status: 'ok'",
  "insertId": "1cudrqsffxoe6d",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "newTrxnNotification",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "xxxx-diligence-xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-11-26T16:59:01.486178952Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "runtime_version": "nodejs18_20231112_18_18_2_RC00",
    "execution_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "logName": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/xxxx-diligence-xxxxx/traces/9bc608f7ef4bb5a829c5cf299dd583a8",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-11-26T16:59:01.626917699Z"
}
```

Why is this code not working for me? I followed the YouTube example to the tee.

Thanks for your help